# comparar si un valor es menor que otro en una tabla jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Buenas, necesito ayuda para realizar lo siguiente:

Necesito comparar si un valor de una columna es menor o mayor que otra columna dentro de una tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo avanzado el siguiente codigo:

```js
$('.a').on('click',function(){
var trPrincipal = this.offsetParent.parentElement; //Buscamos el TR principal
// var firstName = trPrincipal.children[0].outerText; //Capturamos el FirstName
var idproducto=trPrincipal.children[0].outerText;
var nombreprod=trPrincipal.children[1].outerText;
var peso=trPrincipal.children[3].outerText+' '+trPrincipal.children[2].outerText;
var precio=trPrincipal.children[5].outerText;
var stock=trPrincipal.children[6].outerText;
// var lastName = trPrincipal.children[1].outerText+' '+trPrincipal.children[2].outerText; //Capturamos el LastName

$(".othertable").append("<tr><td>"+
idproducto+"</td><td>"+
nombreprod
+"</td><td>"+
peso+"</td><td>"+
stock+"</td><td>"+precio+"</td><td>"+"<input type='number' placeholder='Ingresar cantidad'/></td><td><p class='subTotal'></p></td><td><input type='button' class='btneli' id='idbotoneli' value='Eliminar'></td></tr>");
  trPrincipal.style.display = "none"; //Ocultamos el TR de la Primer Tabla
  var btn_ = document.querySelectorAll(".btneli"); // Buscamos todos los elementos que tengan la clase .btneli
  for(var a in btn_){ //Iteramos la variable btn_
var b = btn_[a];
if(typeof b == "object"){ //Solo necesitamos los objetos
  b.onclick = function (){ //Asignamos evento click
    var trBtn = this.offsetParent.parentElement; // buscamos el tr principal de la segunda tabla
    var firstNameBtn = trBtn.children[0].outerText; //Capturamos el FirstName de la segunda tabla
    trBtn.remove(); // eliminamos toda la fila de la segunda tabla
    var tbl = document.querySelectorAll(".table td:first-child"); //Obtenemos todos los primeros elementos td de la primera tabla
    for(var x in tbl){ //Iteramos los elementos obtenidos
      var y = tbl[x];
      if(typeof y == "object"){ //solo nos interesan los object
        if (y.outerText == firstNameBtn){ //comparamos el texto de la variable y vs el firstNameBtn
           var t = y.parentElement; //capturamos el elemento de la coincidencia
          t.style.display = ""; //actualizamos el estilo display dejándolo en vacío y esto mostrará nuevamente la fila tr de la primera tabla
        }
      }
    }
  }
} //Termina onclick
  }//Termina For

    //Emprezamos buscando todos los inputs tipo Number
  var a = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='number']");
  if(a != undefined || a != null){
a.forEach(function (x){ //De todo el resultado iteramos con un Foreach
  var precio = Number(x.parentElement.previousSibling.textContent); // Localizamos el Precio dentro de la tabla
  x.onkeyup = function (){ //Asignamos un Metodo del teclado; 
    this.offsetParent.nextElementSibling.children[0].innerHTML = (precio * x.value); //Calculamos el subtotal y se lo agregamos en la columna
    generarTotal(); // Ejecutamos una funcion que se genera el Total
  }
});//Foreach
  }//if

  function generarTotal(){ //Funcion que genera el total
var a = document.querySelectorAll(".subTotal"); //Buscamos todos los subtotales
if(a != undefined || a != null){
  var total = new Number(); //creamos variable tipo Number llamada Total
  a.forEach(function (x){ //Iteramos el array a que contiene los subtotales
    total += Number(x.textContent); // Vamos sumando todos los subtotales en la variable total
  });
  var t_ = document.getElementById("total"); //Buscamos el input que tiene Id: total
  t_.value = total.toFixed(2);  // le asignamos por la propiedad value el valos de todos los subtotales con 2 decimales
  generarIGV(); // Generamos el IVa General de las Ventas con la funcion generarIGV
}
  }

  function generarIGV(){ //Funcion que calcula el IVA
var a = document.getElementById("total"); //Buscamos el elemento Total para extraer el total de las ventas
var igv = 0.18; //AQUI se coloca el iva que deseas calcular, par este efecto he puesto el 18%. 
var b = document.getElementById("igv"); // Buscamos el campo con Id igv
var operacion = Number(a.value) * igv; // calculamos el IGV
b.value = operacion.toFixed(2); // Le asignamos al campo con Id igv el IVA mediante la propiedad value.

}
});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">

<table id="idsecond" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                  <thead bgcolor="skyblue">
                    <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Articulo</th>
                <th>Unidad M.</th>
                <th>Peso/Volumen</th>
                <th>Categoria</th>
                <th>P.Unitario</th>
                <th>Stock</th>
                <th>Accion</th>
                      
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Arroz</td>
                    <td>Kilo</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>---</td>
                    <td>18</td>
                      <td>12</td>
                    <td><button class="a">Agregar</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Sal</td>
                    <td>Kilo </td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>---</td>
                    <td>14</td>
                      <td>0</td>
                    <td><button class="a">Agregar</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>Maiz</td>
                    <td>Kilo</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>---</td>
                    <td>12</td>
                      <td>8</td>
                    <td><button class="a">Agregar</button></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
              
              
              

<table class="othertable col-xs-12 table-condensed table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead bgcolor="orange">
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Peso/Volumen</th>
                <th>Stock</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>SubTotal</th>
                <th>Accion</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        
<hr>

  <div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <label for="igv">IGV:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"disabled id="igv">
  </div>
    <div class="form-group  col-sm-4">
    <label for="total">Total:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled id="total">
  </div>
  
</div>
</div>
```

Agradecería enormemente la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algo que puedes hacer con jQuery es lo siguiente:

1. Opcional (aunque conveniente): añade una clase al `input`
2. Añade un controlador para el evento `change`/`keyup`/`keydown`/`input` (o el que más te guste) que hará lo siguiente:

   1. Lee el contenido de la cuarta celda de la columna (donde está el stock)
   2. Compara  el valor del `input` con el valor obtenido en 2.1
   3. Si es mayor: entonces el número introducido no es válido
   4. Si es menor o igual: todo está bien

El código del controlador sería así:

```
// controlador del evento input en la caja de texto
$(".cantidad-check").on("input", function() {
    $this = $(this);
    // leemos el valor del stock y lo parseamos como entero
    var stock = parseInt($this.closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(4)").text());
    // comprobamos si el valor introducido es mayor que el del stock disponible
    if ($this.val() > stock) {
        // si lo es, realiza alguna acción (p.e.: mensaje de error, bordes rojos, etc.)
    } else {
        // si no lo es, no hagas nada o vuelve al estado inicial (p.e. sin bordes rojos)
    }
});
```

Y aquí te dejo una demo. Los bordes se ponen rojos cuando el número es  mayor que el stock, tú puedes poner otra acción como por ejemplo, poner el valor máximo del stock:

```js
$('.a').on('click',function(){
var trPrincipal = this.offsetParent.parentElement; //Buscamos el TR principal
// var firstName = trPrincipal.children[0].outerText; //Capturamos el FirstName
var idproducto=trPrincipal.children[0].outerText;
var nombreprod=trPrincipal.children[1].outerText;
var peso=trPrincipal.children[3].outerText+' '+trPrincipal.children[2].outerText;
var precio=trPrincipal.children[5].outerText;
var stock=trPrincipal.children[6].outerText;
// var lastName = trPrincipal.children[1].outerText+' '+trPrincipal.children[2].outerText; //Capturamos el LastName

$(".othertable").append("<tr><td>"+
idproducto+"</td><td>"+
nombreprod
+"</td><td>"+
peso+"</td><td>"+
stock+"</td><td>"+precio+"</td><td>"+"<input type='number' class='cantidad-check' placeholder='Ingresar cantidad'/></td><td><p class='subTotal'></p></td><td><input type='button' class='btneli' id='idbotoneli' value='Eliminar'></td></tr>");
  trPrincipal.style.display = "none"; //Ocultamos el TR de la Primer Tabla
  var btn_ = document.querySelectorAll(".btneli"); // Buscamos todos los elementos que tengan la clase .btneli
  for(var a in btn_){ //Iteramos la variable btn_
var b = btn_[a];
if(typeof b == "object"){ //Solo necesitamos los objetos
  b.onclick = function (){ //Asignamos evento click
    var trBtn = this.offsetParent.parentElement; // buscamos el tr principal de la segunda tabla
    var firstNameBtn = trBtn.children[0].outerText; //Capturamos el FirstName de la segunda tabla
    trBtn.remove(); // eliminamos toda la fila de la segunda tabla
    var tbl = document.querySelectorAll(".table td:first-child"); //Obtenemos todos los primeros elementos td de la primera tabla
    for(var x in tbl){ //Iteramos los elementos obtenidos
      var y = tbl[x];
      if(typeof y == "object"){ //solo nos interesan los object
        if (y.outerText == firstNameBtn){ //comparamos el texto de la variable y vs el firstNameBtn
           var t = y.parentElement; //capturamos el elemento de la coincidencia
          t.style.display = ""; //actualizamos el estilo display dejándolo en vacío y esto mostrará nuevamente la fila tr de la primera tabla
        }
      }
    }
  }
} //Termina onclick
  }//Termina For

    //Emprezamos buscando todos los inputs tipo Number
  var a = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='number']");
  if(a != undefined || a != null){
a.forEach(function (x){ //De todo el resultado iteramos con un Foreach
  var precio = Number(x.parentElement.previousSibling.textContent); // Localizamos el Precio dentro de la tabla
  x.onkeyup = function (){ //Asignamos un Metodo del teclado; 
    this.offsetParent.nextElementSibling.children[0].innerHTML = (precio * x.value); //Calculamos el subtotal y se lo agregamos en la columna
    generarTotal(); // Ejecutamos una funcion que se genera el Total
  }
});//Foreach
  }//if

  function generarTotal(){ //Funcion que genera el total
var a = document.querySelectorAll(".subTotal"); //Buscamos todos los subtotales
if(a != undefined || a != null){
  var total = new Number(); //creamos variable tipo Number llamada Total
  a.forEach(function (x){ //Iteramos el array a que contiene los subtotales
    total += Number(x.textContent); // Vamos sumando todos los subtotales en la variable total
  });
  var t_ = document.getElementById("total"); //Buscamos el input que tiene Id: total
  t_.value = total.toFixed(2);  // le asignamos por la propiedad value el valos de todos los subtotales con 2 decimales
  generarIGV(); // Generamos el IVa General de las Ventas con la funcion generarIGV
}
  }

  function generarIGV(){ //Funcion que calcula el IVA
var a = document.getElementById("total"); //Buscamos el elemento Total para extraer el total de las ventas
var igv = 0.18; //AQUI se coloca el iva que deseas calcular, par este efecto he puesto el 18%. 
var b = document.getElementById("igv"); // Buscamos el campo con Id igv
var operacion = Number(a.value) * igv; // calculamos el IGV
b.value = operacion.toFixed(2); // Le asignamos al campo con Id igv el IVA mediante la propiedad value.

}
  
  
  
  $(".cantidad-check").on("input", function() {
    $this = $(this);
    var stock = parseInt($this.closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(4)").text());
    if ($this.val() > stock) {
      // esto se ejecuta cuando la cantidad es mayor que el stock
      // para pruebas, yo pongo el borde rojo
      $this.css("border-color", "red");
    } else {
      // esto se ejecuta cuando la cantidad es menor o igual que el stock
      $this.css("border-color", "");
    }
  });
  
});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">

<table id="idsecond" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                  <thead bgcolor="skyblue">
                    <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Articulo</th>
                <th>Unidad M.</th>
                <th>Peso/Volumen</th>
                <th>Categoria</th>
                <th>P.Unitario</th>
                <th>Stock</th>
                <th>Accion</th>
                      
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Arroz</td>
                    <td>Kilo</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>---</td>
                    <td>18</td>
                      <td>12</td>
                    <td><button class="a">Agregar</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Sal</td>
                    <td>Kilo </td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>---</td>
                    <td>14</td>
                      <td>0</td>
                    <td><button class="a">Agregar</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>Maiz</td>
                    <td>Kilo</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>---</td>
                    <td>12</td>
                      <td>8</td>
                    <td><button class="a">Agregar</button></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
              
              
              

<table class="othertable col-xs-12 table-condensed table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead bgcolor="orange">
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Peso/Volumen</th>
                <th>Stock</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>SubTotal</th>
                <th>Accion</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        
<hr>

  <div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <label for="igv">IGV:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"disabled id="igv">
  </div>
    <div class="form-group  col-sm-4">
    <label for="total">Total:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled id="total">
  </div>
  
</div>
</div>
```